# MultiSet: problems with add, remove and equals

Tags: java, multiset

i have some problems with some of my methods for my MultiSet class.
This is a tester, and MultiSet class should get the output: "Succes!" if it works correctly.
This is the tester:

```
public class MultiSetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiSet<String> a = new MultiSet<String>();
    MultiSet<String> b = new MultiSet<String>();

    a.add("Foo");
    a.add("Bar");
    a.add("Foo");
    System.out.println("a:" + a); // test toString

    b.add("Bar");
    b.add("Foo");
    b.add("Bar");
    b.add("Foo");
    System.out.println("b:" + b);

    assert !a.equals(b) : "Failed test 1!"; // test equals
    assert b.remove("Bar") : "Failed test 2!"; // test remove
    assert a.equals(b) : "Failed test 3!";
    for(String s : a) { // test iterator
        assert b.remove(s) : "Failed test 4!";
    }
    assert b.size() == 0 : "Failed test 5!";

    Set<String> baseSet = new HashSet<String>(a);
    assert baseSet.size()==2 : "Failed test 6!";  

    b = new MultiSet<String>(a);
    assert a.equals(b) : "Failed test 7!";

    try {
        assert false;
        System.out.println("Please enable assertions!");
    }
    catch(AssertionError e) {
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }
    }
}
```

And my Multiset class:

```
public class MultiSet<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
{
    private int size = 0;
    private Map<E, Integer> values = new HashMap<E, Integer>();

    public MultiSet()
    {

    }

    public MultiSet(Collection<E> c)
    {
        addAll(c);
    }

    public boolean add()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean remove()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<E>()
        {
            private Iterator<E> iterator = values.keySet().iterator();
            private int remaining = 0;
            private E current = null;

            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return remaining > 0 || iterator.hasNext();
            }

            public E next()
            {
                if (remaining == 0)
                {
                    current = iterator.next();
                    remaining = values.get(current);
                }
                remaining--;
                return current;
            }
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

        public boolean equals(Object object)
        {
            if (this == object) return true;
            if (this == null) return false;
            if (this.getClass() != object.getClass()) return false;
            MultiSet<E> o = (MultiSet<E>) object;
            return o.values.equals(values);
        }


        public int hashCode()
        {
            return values.hashCode()*163 + new Integer(size).hashCode()*389;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String res = "";
            for (E e : values.keySet());
                    //res = ???;
            return getClass().getName() + res;
        }

        public int size()
        {
            return size;
        }
    }
```

Maybe if you could help me on the way with either add or remove, then i can probably work the other one out.

Also, my equals doesn't appear to work correctly,
and I'm unsure about how to work out "res" at String toString. Don't mind my return statement, i'll throw in some brackets etc. later to make it look good.

Thank you for your help.
// Chris

Comment: You should show what you tried for add/remove.  You should also specify exactly what goes wrong.  Also, you have a `size` variable that seems completely useless.

Comment: To Add/Remove objects from my MultiSet

Answer (score 2):

Why not on of use well-tested Google [Guavas's Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)s instead of reinventing the wheel? You can choose one of many implementations:

- ConcurrentHashMultiset,
- EnumMultiset,
- ForwardingMultiset,
- HashMultiset,
- ImmutableMultiset,
- LinkedHashMultiset,
- TreeMultiset

what should cover your use case or - if you really want - implement Multiset interface by yourself, looking into sources of default implemntations.

**EDIT:**

Your implementation breaks `Collecion` interface contract - you cannot return `false` for `add(E e)`. Read [Collection docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29):

> **`boolean add(E e)`**
>
> Parameters:
>
> `e` - element whose presence in this collection is to be ensured
>
> Returns:
>
> `true` if this collection changed as a result of the call
>
> Throws:
>
> `UnsupportedOperationException` - if the add operation is not supported by this collection

If you want to use read-only Multiset use either `ImmutableMultiset` (more specifically [ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(Iterable)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultiset.html#copyOf%28java.lang.Iterable%29)) or implement `Multiset` 
's interface `add(E e)` method throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: I looked through some of those. So, will this work?

@Override
public boolean add(E o){
throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
For my add-method?

Comment: I edited my answer in response to this comment - basically you cannot return `false` from `add` method, it breaks Collection contract.